# Reading textfile with multiple elements into arraylist (set and get)

Tags: java, arraylist, text-files, readfile

I am trying to read from a text file of the type (Artist, Title, Genre, Recordcompany, Release year, Number of songs, Playtime):

The Beatles, Abbey Road, Rock, Apple Records, 1969, 17, 47.16

Sia, 1000 Forms of Fear, Pop, Intertia, 2014, 12, 48.41

Taylor Swift, Speak Now

I have created a CD class:

```js
package q;

public class CD {
  // 
  private String artist;
  private String titel;
  private String genre;
  private String recordcompany;
  private int year; // 
  private int songs; // 
  private double playtime; // 


  public CD() { // 
  }
  public CD(String newArtist, String newTitel) {
    artist = newArtist;
    titel = newTitel;
  }
  public CD(String newArtist, String newTitel, String newGenre, String newRecordcompany, int newYear, int newSongs, double newPlaytime) {
    artist = newArtist;
    titel = newTitel;
    genre = newGenre;
    recordcompany = newRecordcompany;
    year = newYear;
    songs = newSongs;
    playtime = newPlaytime;
  }

  public String getArtist() { //  
    return artist;
  }
  public String getTitel() {
    return titel;
  }
  public String getGenre() {
    return genre;
  }
  public String getRecordcompany() {
    return recordcompany;
  }
  public int getYear() {
    return year;
  }
  public int getsong() {
    return songs;
  }
  public double getPlaytime() {
    return playtime;
  }
  public void setArtist(String newArtist) { // 
    artist = newArtist;
  }
  public void setTitel(String newTitel) {
    titel = newTitel;
  }
  public void setGenre(String newGenre) {
    genre = newGenre;
  }
  public void setRecordcompany(String newRecordcompany) {
    recordcompany = newRecordcompany;
  }
  public void setYear(int newYear) {
    year = newYear;
  }
  public void setSongs(int newSongs) {
    songs = newSongs;
  }
  public void setplaytime(double newPlaytime) {
    playtime = newPlaytime;
  }

  @
  Override public String toString() { // 
    return ("Artist " + artist + System.lineSeparator() + "Titel: " + titel + System.lineSeparator() + "Genre: " + genre + System.lineSeparator() + "Recordcompany: " + recordcompany + System.lineSeparator() + "Year: " + year + System.lineSeparator() + "Songs: " + songs + System.lineSeparator() + "Playtime: " + playtime + System.lineSeparator());
  }
}
```

I am trying to read from the text file and then convert it into a arraylist. I know I have overcomplicated it by first conerting the text file to a string array and then converting it to an arraylist. I would like to use set and get methods when I create the array, if it is possible. I wonder if any of you have any tips for me for how I can make the code less complicated and include set and get methods if possible, thank you.

```js
package q;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class Q {


  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {


    String artist = "";
    String titel = "";
    String genre = "";
    String recordcompany = "";
    String year = "";
    String songs = "";
    String playtime = "";


    try {
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("nej.txt"));
      String line = null;

      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String tmp[] = line.split(",");
        artist = tmp[0];
        titel = tmp[1];

        if (tmp.length > 2) {
          genre = tmp[2];
          recordcompany = tmp[3];
          year = (tmp[4]);
          songs = (tmp[5]);
          playtime = (tmp[6]);
        } else {
          genre = "";
          recordcompany = "";
          year = "";
          songs = "";
          playtime = "";

        }
        List < String > unsorted = Arrays.asList(tmp);
        for (String e: unsorted) {
          System.out.println(e);
        }
      }

      br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
  }
}
```

**EDITED**

```js
package q;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Q {


  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {


    String artist = "";
    String titel = "";
    String genre = "";
    String recordcompany = "";
    int year = 0;
    int songs = 0;
    double playtime = 0.0;



    try {
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("nej.txt"));
      String line = null;

      List < CD > cdsList = new ArrayList < > ();

      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        CD cd = new CD();
        String tmp[] = line.split(",");
        cd.setArtist(tmp[0]);
        cd.setTitel(tmp[1]);

        if (tmp.length > 2) {
          cd.setGenre(tmp[2]);
          cd.setRecordcompany(tmp[3]);
          cd.setYear(Integer.parseInt(tmp[4].trim()));
          cd.setSongs(Integer.parseInt(tmp[5].trim()));
          cd.setplaytime(Double.parseDouble(tmp[6].trim()));

        }
        System.out.println(cdsList);
      }

      br.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: does your text file contain all the details for all the records?? like::: The Beatles, Abbey Road, Rock, Apple Records, 1969, 17, 47.16

Comment: Hey you are directly using the array split and converting it as List why can you make the array of CD and there while setting you can put your if else as well. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Abhishek Some of the records do not contain all of the information, some of them just contain the artist and title.

Comment: @KulbhushanSingh could you develop, I do not fully understand.

Comment: i think you need to modify your data to correct format... your code will not be able to tell which data is corresponding to which field in your POJO...

Comment: ArrayList of your CD POJO would be a good solution. with each field as a key and value pair in a map.

something like this would be easier 
[{"title":"value", "artist":"value","lenght":45},{"title":"value", "artist":"value"}]

Comment: @Abhishek could you give an example of how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("nej.txt"));
          String line = null;

          List < CD > cdsList = new ArrayList < > ();

          while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            CD cd = new CD();
            String tmp[] = line.split(",");
            cd.setArtist(tmp[0]);
            cd.setTitel(tmp[1]);

            if (tmp.length > 2) {
              cd.setGenre(tmp[2]);
              cd.setRecordcompany(tmp[3]);
              cd.setYear(Integer.parseInt(tmp[4].trim()));
              cd.setSongs(Integer.parseInt(tmp[5].trim()));
              cd.setplaytime(Double.parseDouble(tmp[6].trim()));

            }
            cdsList.add(cd);

          }
          System.out.println(cdsList);

          br.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
          System.out.println(e);
        }

}
```

Comment: Don't forget to parse 'year', 'songs' and 'playtime' for converting to numeric data type(int and double)

Comment: @niyasc  When I use this method (I parse year, songs and playtime) I get the error: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 1969" at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)

Comment: parse year and songs as Integer.parseInt(String) and playtime as Double.parseDouble(String)

Comment: i think in 1969 you are having whitespace as well add trim to it. I will edit the answer

Comment: Just `trim` white spaces before you parse.

Comment: When you are using trim just make sure it's not null otherwise you run into NullPointerException

Comment: @KulbhushanSingh when I print the arraylist I just get a blank array, ([]). Is it empty then, or does not it work printing the array by using System.out.println(cdsList); ?

Comment: try debugging it and see if its coming in this block or not. I have just changed your inside while loop thing.

Comment: @KulbhushanSingh it resets after each of the CDs go through, the list size is = 0.

Comment: Where you have declared your List, that is important. It should be outside your loop

Comment: @KulbhushanSingh I have added the edited script in my question, could you have a look, thank you.

Comment: I have edited my answer with complete main method. try that. We have missed adding cd object to the list

Comment: @KulbhushanSingh It works, the only problem is that there is an "," before Artist:. How do I remove it? And is it possible to have blanks behind the details that are blank instead of "null"

Comment: It is with your toString() overriding in your CD class. Try to debug this things, this will help you to learn

Comment: @KulbhushanSingh Thank you so much for the help

Comment: np  return ("Artist " + artist + System.lineSeparator() + "Titel: " + titel + System.lineSeparator() + "Genre: " + genre + System.lineSeparator() + "Recordcompany: " + recordcompany + System.lineSeparator() + "Year: " + year + System.lineSeparator() + "Songs: " + songs + System.lineSeparator() + "Playtime: " + playtime );